# Mesh displaying strangely in edit mode- vertices and faces show, edges don't

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I've been using sculpt mode on a mesh (with dyntopo) and using edit mode to make tweaks, but this time when I entered edit mode some of the mesh was displaying strangely. The shape of the mesh still shows, and the vertices and faces still show, but there are no visible edges between them, and the affected areas don't work with proportional editing. I can't think of anything that would intentionally cause this, but I'm hoping it isn't a bug because I don't know how I would recover my mesh... Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try pressing Alt+H to unhide while in Edit mode. Does anything change if activating Dyntopo again in Sculpt mode, doing some strokes, then going to Edit mode? Does sculpting work at all in these areas?

Comment: The first two do nothing, but yes sculpting is still possible. I've just reloaded the file from my last save and am redoing any lost work, rather than trying to figure this out, but it's still a curious occurrence.

Comment: This case is quite localized, so if possible share the file (a piece of your model with this behaviour) on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add a link here. This could be a bug and if it is it should be reported.